# How to ng-click using TypeScript and ionicBootstrap?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm not sure how the `ng-click` works in Ionic 2 with Typescript.

Basically, my Ionic app looks like this:

```
class MyApp { 
 ...
 showPopup() { .. } 
 ...
}
ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

Edit: I also tried adding the function in the specific-page.ts file, but it doesn't work.

I try to use the showPopup() inside an `ng-click` but obviously, there's something missing, and I can't find any information about it in the documentation.

```
ng-click="showPopup()"
```

Do you have any idea what I am missing? I know without Typescript $scope must be used, but what about with Typescript and IonicBootstrap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ionic2 is based on Angular 2 and the proper way to use the click event ([docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html#!#click-event)) is

```
// component code
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  public items: Array<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
  }

  public open(event, item) {
    alert('Open ' + item);
  }

}
```

And then in your view

```
<!-- View -->
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-title>
      <span>My App</span>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="open($event, item)">
        {{ item }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

As you can see in the code, I'm declaring the click handler like this `(click)="open($event, item)"` and sending both the event and the item (declared in the *ngFor) to the `open()` method (declared in the component code).

If you don't need to get info from the event, you can just do `(click)="open(item)"` and modify the open method like this public `open(item) { ... }`

Comment: Ah i got confused with angular 1! Thanks! Is there any list of the available variables like $event for templates?

Answer (score 2):

In your html component, that you want it to be clickable, you need to use `(click)='showPopup()'`. Like say:

```
<button (click)='showPopup()'>Click here</button>
```

In your typescript, the code is correct:

```
class MyApp { 
 ...
 showPopup() { .. } 
 ...
}
```

Additionally you can pass parameters as you would normally pass. `(click)=showPopup(param1,param2,..)`.

Comment: What is the change to use ng-click ?